# How doing a sql select with where mandatories joining 'or wheres'?

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I need making this select:

`select * from posts where active = 1       //mandatory
                     where url <> 'thisurl' //mandatory
                     or where id1 = 1 
                     or where id2 = 2`

Is it clear to understand?
In adition i´m using `Codeigniter active record`, so if someone could help
me in translating that, i´ll be thankfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Codeigniter query builder lingo:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('active', 1);
$this->db->where('url !=', 'thisurl');
$this->db->group_start();
     $this->db->or_where('id1', 1);
     $this->db->or_where('id2', 2);
$this->db->group_end();

$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

The above will always enforce active=1 and url <> 'thisurl' and also enforce that at least id1=1 or id2=2

Answer (score 1):

Try like below

```
 select * from posts where active = 1       //mandatory
                     and url <> 'thisurl' //mandatory
                     and ( id1 =1 or id2 =2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
SELECT* 
FROM posts 
WHERE active = 1       //
AND url <> 'thisurl' //mandatory
OR id1 = 1 
OR id2 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about parentheses!

```
SELECT * from posts 
WHERE (active = 1 AND url <> 'thisurl') OR id1 = 1 OR id2 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $where to make easy where query

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('posts');
$where ="(
        active = 1       //mandatory
        where url <> 'thisurl' //mandatory
        or where id1 = 1 
        or where id2 = 2
        )";
$this->db->where($where);
$result = $this->db->get();
```